# How to add and automatically update a slides journey map to every slide on Google Slides

Tags: graphics, slideshow, google-slides

Me and my team of 300 people are working from home since covid. Every now and then someone is presenting and recording the meeting. Sometimes we end up looking for a particular section of the presentation. However, it is very frustrating and time consuming to hunt for the required section through the whole recording. I was wondering if there is a way to automatically add some sort of "Slides Journey Map" at top or bottom of every slide. Something like a dynamic contents at the top/bottom of every slide. So that it is easy to know which section a speaker is talking about.